# How to replace master branch with experiment branch

Tags: git

I have two branches: master and experiment. Both of them evolved separately and are very different now. Now I am ready to make experiment branch my master branch.

If I try

```
git checkout master
git merge experiment
```

I get tons and tons of error.

What is the easiest way to get experiment branch to become master without loosing all the history of experiment branch.

I have already created a backup of master branch as release 1.0 like this

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b release_1
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? And do you want to *merge* the changes in the master, or just replace the master with the experiment branch?

Comment: I guess the errors are actually "conflicts"

Comment: poor choice of words. I should have said conflicts. But there are so many and I don't really want to resolve them.

Comment: Are these private or public branches? i.e. Is anyone else working on these branches?

Comment: @Mauricio: Since the OP already used and accepted your answer, I'm assuming they were private.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming these are *private* branches (i.e. nobody else is working on them), you can just set `master` to `experiment` like this:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard experiment
```

If these are public branches, you'll probably want to merge and resolve conflicts, as [Jefromi explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134276/how-to-replace-master-branch-with-experiment-branch/4134538#4134538).

Comment: Doesn't this just "copy over" the contents from the experiment branch to the current one? That way you will lose the history of the branch..

Comment: @poke: reset doesn't copy anything. This just sets `master` exactly were `experiment` is.

Comment: @Mauricio: Yeah, but it throws away the original master (and with that all new commits that are not in the experiment branch) and makes master a "copy" of the experiment branch, pointing at the same HEAD.

Comment: @Mauricio: I think it was just poor choice of works on poke's part - you do indeed lose whatever history on master wasn't in experimental.

Comment: @poke, @Jefromi: yes, that's what I understand the OP wants. He wants to replace it. He already made a "backup" branch of master as release_1.

Comment: @poke: I wouldn't use the word "copy" in this context as there is really no copy.

Comment: @Mauricio: I know, that's why I put it in quotation marks ;) Sorry for the bad wording, but I couldn't think of a better word then.

Comment: @Mauricio: Having made a backup doesn't always mean that it's the best idea. Rewriting history can be a scary thing - and it's totally possible to work past the conflicts *without* doing it.

Comment: Great answer. Sorry about all the (largely pointless) back-and-forth!

Answer (score 12):

There are a few possibilities here, depending on exactly what you mean by "replace". You almost certainly took the right approach to start with - merging is generally the way to go. The "errors" you saw were merge conflicts, presumably. If you know for sure that, whenever there's a conflict, you want to use the version from your experimental branch, you could do:

```
# resolve conflicts by taking the version from experimental
# non-conflicting content is merged normally
git checkout master
git merge -Xtheirs experimental
```

If you want to use the version in experimental for *everything*, not just where there are conflicts, there are a ton of ways (there's not actually a merge strategy for this). The simplest:

```
# do the merge the other way around
git checkout experimental
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge experimental

# do the merge the right way
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit experimental  # merge, but stop before committing
git checkout experimental .         # check out content, but don't switch branch
git commit                          # commit the merge
```

The ways others have suggested (`reset --hard`, `branch -M`) will work, sort of, but since they don't create a merge commit, your master branch moves in a non-fast-forward way, potentially causing headaches for others who need to pull from this repo. Generally, I'd say that's the right answer only if these branches are unpublished.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. The OP doesn't want to merge, he wants to replace the branch.

Comment: @Mauricio: No, the OP wants to replace the *content* of the branch, avoiding resolving the conflicts. You can have it both ways - and if you merge, it means that others will be able to cleanly pull the update. (This, to me, is a clearly likely case of needing to do X, and asking how to do Y to accomplish it, when you can actually do Y', which will make everyone happier.)

Comment: @Jefromi: actually, it seems that you assumed it's a *public* branch, while I assumed it's a *private* branch.

Comment: @Mauricio: Pretty much, yes. I generally assume public unless told otherwise, because I'd rather mistakenly tell someone to be too careful than tell someone to do something which angers everyone else on their development team.

Comment: @Jefromi: with a public branch: yes, merge. With a private branch: no need to, it's simpler to reset the branch in this case.

Comment: @Jefromi: let's not assume and ask the OP :-)

Comment: @Mauricio: Yep, in complete agreement. I'm just very cautious - especially with the knowledge that even if the OP's branch is private, someone else with a public branch could google and find this question. (And when there are already answers assuming the opposite, I prefer to simply provide the other answer.)

Comment: @Jefromi: just updated my answer so that nobody accidentally messes up his repo by blindly following my advice :-)

Comment: Your "the other way around" worked perfectly for me, preserving the history and all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your branch (from experiment):
`git branch -M master`