# Overwrite master with local (Git)

Tags: git

I'd like to know to overwrite master, with what I have in my current working directory.

Thanks.

P.S.  I'm very new to Git.

Comment: And with "master" you mean your master branch? Does this mean you basically want to "reset" your branch so that it only includes the files currently existing in your working directory?

Comment: By master I mean the master branch, and basically, I have another branch, I'll call it X. I want to replace the head of the master branch with the head of the X branch.

Comment: So, it sounds like you want to delete your master branch and rename X to master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be enough:

```
git checkout -B master X
```

From the [`git checkout` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> If `-B` is given, `<new_branch>` is created if it doesn't exist; otherwise, it is reset.
>   This is the transactional equivalent of:

```
$ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
$ git checkout <branch>
```

> that is to say, the branch is not reset/created unless "`git checkou`t" is successful.

This is a bit shorter than the the other options described in "[How to replace master branch with experiment branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134276/how-to-replace-master-branch-with-experiment-branch)".